# Creating a turn queue for a RPG

Tags: actionscript-3, game-engine

I'm trying to create a turn-based RPG where the player characters and the enemy characters each possess a `speed` stat. Using this stat, I would like to create an on-screen display of the next, say, 6 people in the queue to take their turn.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to turn the `speed` stat of each character into a useable number to determine turn order.

For example:

```
char1.speed = 10;
char2.speed = 20;
char3.speed = 80;
```

In a situation like this, I would like to be able to create a turn queue such that `char3` takes two or three turns ahead of the other characters, since his character is significantly faster than the others. So the on-screen display would show portraits of `char3`, `char3`, `char2`, `char3`, `char1`, `char3`, for example. (I can make the queue display and make it re-sort itself; my struggle is making a changeable turn order that is based on a character's `speed` stat.)

Another issue that I'm struggling with is that I want to be able to modify a character's speed by spells, potions, etc that may end up changing the turn order mid-battle. I anticipate having an `updateTurns()` function which will re-sort my queue when this happens... is the best way to go about this giving each character *two* speed stats, `baseSpeed` and `adjSpeed`, for example? So that the `baseSpeed` remains the same no matter what happens through spells and items, while the `adjSpeed` represents a character's speed at that particular moment in battle?

Thanks for the help, and hopefully I've made sense. This is my first time posting here, so if I need any more clarification or whatnot, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be relatively straight forward. First you need your divisor, i.e, how to determine what a single turn is. I assume 10? So get how many turns each character gets, set up a constant with the single turn speed in your character base class;

```
public static const TURN:uint = 10;
```

Then you can do something like this to get each players' turns;

```
char2.speed / character.TURN = // how many turns each player gets.
```

Then you can have a main loop, which is an array of your characters, and a sub loop, which loops through each character, removing a turn each time, and adding the char to the queue each time. Once turn = 0. The next character will be iterated by the main loop. Once you have a queue, you could shuffle it afterwards to change the order up a bit. Break it into two tasks.

Once you have `turns`for each character, you could deduct some `turns`, so also store a `speedPenalty` in each char which is normally 0, but if hit by a spell, change it to `x`. Then your main forumula is actually;

```
(char2.speed / character.TURN) - speedPenalty
```

If you do this, you'll have to make sure each char can never go below 1 turn. Or, as you say, have a base speed, and a current speed, and then deduct from current speed and use that to calculate turns, and reset it to base speed once the spell wears off.